# Specifying layouts for mobile and wear modules

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, mobile, wear-os

**I created a new project from scratch for both mobile (minSdkVersion at 9) and wear (minSdkVersion at 20) modules**, and I was wondering how to specify layouts for wear-round and wear-square (do I need to play around with the WatchViewStub class a bit?) devices. Like, I am aware that the data gets sent from the handheld to the wear, but how can I configure it so the app runs on the wear-round and wear-square layouts (particularly using only the XML files) accordingly?

Here's my mobile\...\activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hello mobile world!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As for the layouts under the wear module, everything is defaulted (I didn't modify anything), so that includes, but not limited to, the inflater via the implementation of the WatchViewStub class, XMLs for round and square screens that should output "Hello Square World!" and "Hello Round World!", respectively, and etc.

Here's my untouched wear\...\MainActivity:

```
package dpark.gameoflife;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

... And then here's what I get from the wear virtual emulators:

[image]

Why does my round virtual emulator above not appear round?

[image]

Thanks, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource qualifiers `layout-round` and `layout-square` were only introduced in SDK level 23. To target earlier levels with different layouts for round and square displays, you'll want to either use `WatchViewStub` or `BoxInsetLayout`, both [documented here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html).

Depending on your release schedule, though, you could also just target SDK 23 on the wearable side. 23 is on most watches already, and Google has said that all Wear devices will be getting it soon(ish).

And as for your round emulator displaying square... there's no good explanation, but they just do that sometimes. Restart it a couple of times, delete and recreate it if you have to, and eventually it should sort itself out.